# AWS ALB/NLB Rewriting Requests to HAProxy Instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, load-balancing, haproxy, amazon-elb

I'd like to use load-balanced HAProxy instances to reverse-proxy one or more S3 buckets.

AWS CLI s3 and s3api commands work great against the individual HAProxy instances if I supply "--endpoint-url=http://HAPROXY". However, when I try to direct those commands to an AWS Application or Network Load Balancer in front of them (--endpoint-url=http://ALB-OR-NLB), I get a weird effect where the load balancer appears to rewrite the target bucket's name with its own FQDN, i.e. "ALB-OR-NLB". Here's an example of an error I receive (with data changed):

```
<Error><Code>NoSuchBucket</Code><Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message><BucketName>``MY-LOAD-BALANCER-ID.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com``</BucketName><RequestId>BLAH</RequestId><HostId>LONG_STRING</HostId></Error>
```

In this example, ALB-OR-NLB is MY-LOAD-BALANCER-ID.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: S3 works based on the `Host` header of the http request. You'll need HAProxy to modify that (which will only work if HAProxy is terminating SSL). Any reason to not just use cloudfront instead?

Comment: Yes, this is a pre-PrivateLink gambit to force routing large uploads over a high-bandwidth link, not a serving solution.

Thanks for the info, but I'm still unclear on why the Host header is preserved when I point directly at an HAProxy instance, but not when I go to one first through an ALB or NLB.

Comment: That is strange, I would expected both cases to not work.

Comment: Well your comment about SSL may be the key point. I am testing with HTTP as a POC, but maybe that's what's tripping me up.